# Running multiple Javascripts from CodeBehind C#

Tags: javascript, c#, code-behind

I have an ASP.net application that, on one page, I need to run multiple javascripts from C# codebehind.  The application sends a transaction to a remote server.  At the start of the routine I want to display a message 'Please Wait'.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "ShowPleaseWait()", true);
```

After the transaction is done i want to hide the message.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "HidePleaseWait()", true);
```

Next I need to print a receipt

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "CreditCard()", true);
```

Only the first script will run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine you JS into one string:

```
var js = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">ShowPleaseWait(); HidePleaseWait(); CreditCard();</script>"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", js, true);
```

Comment: Maxim, thanks for your response.   I could combine the last two, but that still leaves me the need to run two scripts.  The first one runs immediately, while the last two run at the end.  My issue is how to run multiple scripts, which I have researched and can't find a solution.  Am I missing something by you declaring the var js?

Comment: @Charles If you want to call them in parallel you have to edit your question.  Otherwise I don't understand what do you mean "runs immediately, while the last two run at the end"

Comment: On button Click run 'ShowPleaseWait();  Then my code will process the transaction information and send to the webserver.           [BtnProcess_Click] | ShowPleaseWait() |                                                    var response=controller.ProcessRequest<ChargeResponse>(apiContext, request); |                                                                                                       if (response.Success)   HidePleaseWait()  CreditCard.  Hope this helps.  Not good with editing comments.